# Changing the system of PDE by diffeomorphism and differentiate a composition

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, parabolic-pde, ricci-flow

This problem comes from the book Hamilton's Ricci flow.

Given a smooth functional $f$, and following system. $$\partial_t f=-(\Delta f+R)$$ If there exist a 1 parameter family of diffeomorphism $\Psi(t):M\to M$ by $$\partial_t\Psi(t)=\nabla_{g(t)}f(t), \Psi(0)=id_M$$ Show that $\tilde{f}:=f\circ\Psi(t)$ satisfy $$\partial_t\tilde{f}=-\tilde{\Delta}\tilde{f}+|\tilde{\nabla}\tilde{f}|^2-\tilde{R}$$

For the solution \begin{align*}
\partial_t\tilde{f}&=\partial_t(f\circ\Psi)\\
                   &=(\partial_t f)\circ\Psi+\langle({\nabla}{f})\circ\Psi,\partial_t\Psi\rangle_{g(t)}\\
&=-(\Delta f+R)\circ\Psi+|\nabla f\circ\Psi|^2_{g}\\
&=-\tilde{\Delta}\tilde{f}+|\tilde{\nabla}\tilde{f}|^2-\tilde{R}
\end{align*}

I am having trouble in understanding the second line$\langle({\nabla}{f})\circ\Psi,\partial_t\Psi\rangle_{g(t)}$ comes from. I thought it is just usual  Chain rule.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is just the chain rule. But since $f$ depends on the time parameter $t$
in this case, the composition $\tilde{f}=f\circ\Psi(t)$ should be read as $\tilde{ f}(x,t)=f(\Psi(t)(x), t)$.

Comment: Oh! thank you for your answer. I ignore the positions also depends on time.